# Where is defined lispobj struct in SBCL sources

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

My question is self-explanatory. I'm grepping for ages  and I can't find it ...

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lispobj` is not a struct, just a typedef. It is defined in `src/runtime/runtime.h` currently after line 234:

```
#if 64 == N_WORD_BITS
#define LOW_WORD(c) ((pointer_sized_uint_t)c)
#define OBJ_FMTX "lx"
typedef uintptr_t lispobj;
#else
#define OBJ_FMTX "x"
#define LOW_WORD(c) ((long)(c) & 0xFFFFFFFFL)
/* fake it on alpha32 */
typedef unsigned int lispobj;
#endif
```